# Proving that interval is subset of another interval

Tags: real-analysis

let

$I_n=[n, \infty)$

Prove that $I_{n+1} \subseteq I_n$.

So although that is pretty obvious I do not know how to prove it nicely.

for $I_{n}$ the minimum of the set would be n, hence all $k \in \mathbb{R} \geq n \in I_n$

for $I_{n+1}$ the minimum of the set would be n+1, hence all $l \in \mathbb{R} \geq n+1 \in I_{n+1}$.

How can I just argue that $I_{n+1} \subseteq I_{n}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ n\ge 0$. To prove that a set $ A$ is a subset of $ B$, you should prove that any element of $ A$ is in $ B$.

Take an arbitrary element $ x$ of $ I_{n+1}$.

$$x\in I_{n+1}\implies x\in[n+1,+\infty)$$
$$\implies x\ge n+1$$
$$\implies x\ge n$$
$$\implies x\in I_n$$

thus $$I_{n+1}\subset I_n$$

Comment: Thank you, perfectly explained.